# iOS: value not coming as String?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my code, I set array inside a `NSMutableDictionary` as

```
if (array.count > 0) {
            [self.filters setValue:array forKey:[self getKey:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section] intValue]]];
        }
```

where `array` is

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

When the receiving code receives it, I tried to join the values in array as

```
if ([item objectForKey:@"category_filter"] != nil) {
        NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"category_filter"], nil];
        NSString *categories = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];

        NSLog(@"value:%@", categories);
    }
```

where `item` is `(NSMutableDictionary *)item`

When I see log, I see as

```
2014-06-24 17:43:12.520 yelp[69744:70b] value:(
    "Bagels (bagels)",
    "Bakeries (bakeries)"
)
```

so they are not joined yet. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, I've been programming for 40 years, and I can't figure out what you're doing with that first code segment.  Break it up into 3-4 lines so you can understand it and debug it.

Comment: And try NSLogging your `array` object before joining.  What you'll see is an array inside an array, since you for some reason used `arrayWithObjects` on an array to construct your `array` value.

Comment: @HotLicks, you should post your info as an answer so the OP can accept it. (I agree with you that the first code block is awfully confusing.)

Comment: `[[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.section] intValue]` should just be `indexPath.section`, and if `self.filters` is the `NSMutableDictionary`, you should be using `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Hot Licks commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398542/ios-value-not-coming-as-string#comment37740197_24398542),

I had to make change as

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[item objectForKey:@"category_filter"]];
```

instead of

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[item objectForKey:@"category_filter"]];
```

Comment: You may, with my blessing, accept this answer after the required waiting period.